# How to make effect of onclick event not fluctuating

Tags: javascript

```
function change(){
    jQuery(document).on("click", "#formvalid", function (event) {
        $(':input').each(function() {  // finding all input tags 
            if ($(this).val() == '') { // If value is null then changing the style of input tag
                $('#content').html( "<span class='red'>Hello <b>Again</b></span>" );
            }
        }); 
    });
}
```

I am using this code and after click event occurs it gives output for a moment and then  it is fluctuating to original one. I want that output hello again steady even after execution of click funciton.

Comment: can u add this in fiddle?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/9Uq8B/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `#formvalid` is a submit button, so when you click on the button the form is submitted. If you don't have an `action` URL on the form, the page will just reload.

If you don't want to submit the form, [you have to prevent it](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
function change(){
    jQuery(document).on("click", "#formvalid", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // ...
    });
}
```

Alternatively, if you *never* want to submit the form with that button, change the type of the button, e.g.

```
<button id="formvalid" type="button">Validate</button>
```

On the other hand, if you want to run the handler on every form submission, you should really be listening for [the `submit` event on the form itself](http://api.jquery.com/submit/), not for the click event on the button.